# How to 'order by' a variable in Python and SQL?

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've had a look at [this solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646301/passing-a-column-name-in-a-select-statement-in-python). But I don't quite fully understand what is going on, hence I don't know how to use a similar technique in my code.

```
order = "Movies.Rating_IMDB ASC"

general = db.execute (
    """
    SELECT Movies.Movie_ID, Movies.Name, Movies.Year, Movies.Image
    FROM Movie_Genre
    JOIN Movies ON Movie_Genre.Movie_ID = Movies.Movie_ID
    JOIN Genres ON Movie_Genre.Genre_ID = Genres.Genre_ID
    WHERE Genres.Genre = ?
    ORDER BY ?;
    """,
    (str(selectedGenre), order,)
    )
basic = general.fetchall()
```

Comment: Look at Martijn's answer.

Comment: I have.. it says it doesnt recognize "{}" when i try it. Could you help by telling me how i could do it in my version of the code

Comment: There is no `{}` in the code you've shown.

Comment: As in when i attempt to use  { } in order to make it work

Comment: And how should anybody else know what you've attempted?

Comment: I've just told you that { } did not work, and also that i do not understand the concept of the answer in the one linked.. I just need some help, can you help or not??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114240/discussion-between-rq14-and-cl).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. And when you do not understand a specific piece of code, learn about it, and if you fail, ask about that.

Comment: What do you think im doing? I'm asking about it.. can someone explain?