# Sqlite - How to select where "variable1" = "variable2"?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

How do i write an Sqlite select with Where a variable category is an variable and also the search condition is a variable?

I tried it like this:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM OrderList WHERE ? = ?',  (category_string,search_condition_string))
```

But that wont work. How do i do it?

Background:

1. I have a search field (text entry)
2. I have a drop down list to choose in which category the search condition should met
3. after hitting a search button or enter i would like to select everything from an category where the search condition met

Comment: Column names can not be passed as arguments like that. And why would you even need to do that?

Comment: Could be that i am going the wrong way. I have a "Filter"-like function in my gui and a search function. So the category is choosen in an drop down list and the search conditon is set in an text entry. After hitting the search button i want to select all from a category where the search condition met.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646301/passing-a-column-name-in-a-select-statement-in-python

Comment: It's my pleasure!